# "Recently Used Items" user interface control like Kindle Fire.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, kindle-fire

I use Kindle Fire and I like their "Recently Used Items" user interface (just above favorite shelf). I want to implement that kind of control in ASP.NET web application.

Is it possible? If yes how?

I am trying to get something working with Slider but its not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into placing the details of each "used item" in either a cookie or localStorage, and then loading/reading from that when the page loads.

Comment: I am not concern about how to get data but I am concern about "that" effect. How can we mimic that effect scrolling left/right and view recently used item. I am more concerned about getting that visual effect.